# Can you use normal CSS with React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using create-react-app and have read bad things about inline styles so I wanted to use css modules however they aren't supported by create-react-app at this time. Can I literally just use plain old css in one big file? Also with this approach how do I style a react component. For example I have a component and I give it a class name: `<card className="cardStyle" />`. Why does this not work? I want to bed able to position it just like I would a div.

Comment: yes, you can. React just generates HTML, it does not change anything about the way CSS work.

Answer (score 1):

it's certainly possible, you may have plain old CSS classes in a style.css somewhere, but you'll have to make sure your app includes it,

e.g. have in your `App.js`

```
import './style.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to do the following;

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Button.css'; // Tell Webpack that Button.js uses these styles

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    // You can use them as regular CSS styles
    return <div className="Button" />;
  }
}
```

See: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `CSS Modules` might be better way:

`CSS Modules` have `.module.css` in their file name, like `styles.module.css`. Naming it so is important it avoids serious issue in plain CSS when having same CSS class names in different CSS files.

---

File : **styles.module.css**

```
.myClass1 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

---

File : **App.js**

```
import styles from'./styles.module.css';

<div   className={styles['myClass1']}  >
   some content
</div>
```

---

By default supported by `Create React App` - https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html
This can done using simple steps

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

---

Links:
. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/
. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-style-react-apps-with-css/

---

2. If you want to use `normal css` but want more flexibilities like `props to css`, and open to `install more dependencies` then alternatives are:

. https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction
. https://styled-components.com/

Some are migrating `styled-components` to `emotion`, so may be `emotion` is better way to start with.
See https://storybook.js.org/blog/541-components-from-styled-components-to-emotion/

---